# ¿Cómo se realizan pruebas unitarias con Moq en una app con Clean Arquitectura y Patron Repository para los repositorios en C#?

Tags: c#, pruebas-unitarias, repositorio, repository, clean-architecture

Muy buenas a todos, espero se encuentren bien si están leyendo esto, pero estoy aprendiendo sobre pruebas unitarias y tengo varios problemas al llegar a los mock. Comienzo explicando que  tengo las siguientes abstracciones de interfaces en un proyecto C#

```
using Licitapp.Domain.Models;

namespace Licitapp.Domain.Abstractions;

public interface IAccountRepository
{
    Task<Account?> Get(Guid id);
}


namespace Licitapp.Domain.Abstractions;

public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    IAccountRepository Accounts { get; }
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Y las siguientes implementaciones de las interfaces.

```
using Licitapp.Domain.Models;
using Licitapp.Domain.Abstractions;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Licitapp.Infrastructure.Context;

namespace Licitapp.Infrastructure.Repositories;
public class AccountRepository(LicitappContext licitappContext) : IAccountRepository
{
    private readonly LicitappContext _licitappContext = licitappContext;

    public async Task<Account?> Get(Guid id) =>
        await _licitappContext.Accounts.FirstOrDefaultAsync(account => account.Id.Equals(id));
}

using Licitapp.Domain.Abstractions;
using Licitapp.Infrastructure.Context;

namespace Licitapp.Infrastructure.Repositories;
public class UnitOfWork(LicitappContext licitappContext, IAccountRepository accounts)
    : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly LicitappContext _licitappContext = licitappContext;

    public IAccountRepository Accounts { get; } = accounts;

    public void Dispose() => _licitappContext.Dispose();

    public async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync() => await _licitappContext.SaveChangesAsync();

}
```

Y este es mi contexto

```
using Licitapp.Domain.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Licitapp.Infrastructure.Context;
public class LicitappContext(DbContextOptions<LicitappContext> options)
    : DbContext(options)
{
    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Account>(account =>
        {
            // Primary Key
            account.HasKey(account => account.Id);

            // Properties
            account.Property(account => account.Email).HasMaxLength(150).IsRequired();
            account.Property(account => account.Password).HasMaxLength(16).IsRequired();
            account.Property(account => account.DisplayName).HasMaxLength(32).IsRequired();
            account.Property(account => account.CreatedAt).IsRequired();
            account.Property(account => account.UpdatedAt).IsRequired();

            // Index
            account.HasIndex(account => account.Email).IsUnique();

        });
    }

}
```

Intento hacer pruebas unitarias, de UnitOfWork y AccountRepository. Tengo una prueba para el AccountRepository

```
using Licitapp.Domain.Models;
using Licitapp.Infrastructure.Context;
using Licitapp.Infrastructure.Repositories;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Moq;

namespace Licitapp.Test.Interface_Adapters.Gateways;

[TestFixture]
public class AccountRepositoryTest
{
    [Test]
    public async Task GetAccountById_ShouldReturnAccount()
    {
        // Arrange
        var accountId = Guid.NewGuid();
        var mockContext = new Mock<LicitappContext>();
        var mockDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<Account>>();
        mockContext.Setup(c => c.Accounts).Returns(mockDbSet.Object);
        mockDbSet.Setup(d => d.FindAsync(It.IsAny<Guid>())).ReturnsAsync(new Account { Id = accountId });
        var accountRepository = new AccountRepository(mockContext.Object);

        // Act
        var result = await accountRepository.Get(accountId);

        // Assert
        Assert.That(result, Is.Not.Null);
        Assert.That(result.Id, Is.EqualTo(accountId));
    }
}
```

Pero el resultado de la prueba me arroja lo siguiente
System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: c => c.Accounts
Non-overridable members (here: LicitappContext.get_Accounts) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.

No he podido dar con la solución, si alguno con su experiencia sabe o conoce sobre este tipo de pruebas con Moq, agreadecido si me puede aclarar porque se da el problema.